# Excel VBA Use ADO Command Object to Call Stored Query in Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures, ado

I'm trying to call a stored query in my Access database that requires one parameter (criteria).
When I try this I get runtime error '3265': "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal" when it reaches the line cmd(1)=userName.

[image]

The msgbox line above that one shows me that there is a parameter count of 0, but there should be a count of 1.

```
Function getUserLevelCmd() As String
 Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
 Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
 Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

 Set conn = makeConnection()

 cmd.CommandText = "accessLevelByUN"
 cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

 cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

 cmd.Parameters.Refresh

 MsgBox (cmd.Parameters.Count)

 cmd(1) = userName

 Set rs = cmd.Execute

 rs.Close
 conn.Close
 Set cmd = Nothing
End Function
```

I double and triple checked all my spellings. I know that the connection to my database is good, because I am able to use it to do other SQL queries. It's just stored queries that have parameters that I'm stuck on.
I based my attempt on this tutorial from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/calling-a-stored-procedure-with-a-command?view=sql-server-ver15

Here is what the design-view of this simple query looks like in Access (the parameter being circled in red):
[image]

The SQL-view of the  of the query in access:
[image]

Anyone have any tips?

Comment: Edit question to post the SQL statement.

Comment: @June7 I added the sql-view of the Access stored query. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Should be text instead of image to allow copy/paste but since image is readable and query short, can live with. I will have to do some testing. I don't normally use dynamic parameterized queries and never needed to do this from Excel. So unless someone else provides answer, I will be back later. Why is Excel involved?

Comment: @June7 it's school project, so I have to do it the way they say, lol. Otherwise, I wouldn't be using VBA at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adCmdStoredProc doesn't seem to be designed for MsAccess queries. Change it to adCmdTable. Also, when setting the parameter values they are indexed from zero.

```
 Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
 Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
 Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

 Set conn = makeConnection()
 cmd.CommandText = "accessLevelByUN"
 cmd.CommandType = adCmdTable

 cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

 cmd.Parameters.Refresh

 MsgBox (cmd.Parameters.Count)

 cmd.Parameters(0) = userName

 Set rs = cmd.Execute
...
```

Comment: That's it! Weird that MS used indexing from 1 in their tutorial, but I would have figured that one out quick. The real problem was the command type. Thank you so much!